# How to fix Ubuntu touch calendar and a Google calendar out of sync?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, calendar

My Ubuntu touch calendar and my Google calendar are out of sync. 
The remote calendar on Google is correct. How do I reinitialize the calendar on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to fix a bad synchronisation between Google calendar and the calendar app is following this steps:

1. In Settings > Account, remove the Google account.
2. Close the Calendar application on the phone (explained [here](http://itsfoss.com/close-running-apps-ubuntu-phone/) how to do this).
3. In Settings > Account, create again the Google account.
4. In Settings > Account > Google, check at least the Calendar box.
5. Launch the Calendar app on the Phone. In the upper right menu (button with three horizontal bars), go to Calendars and select your Calendar again.
6. Synchronisation will start.
   After a surprisingly short time, your local calendar is reinitialised and identical, as far as I can see, to the Google Calendar.

Voilà. Let us hope that the developpers of the app will soon fix all the bugs that cause the app to be out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that the calendar application has access to your Google calendar by checking the Google entry in the "Accounts" section of the system settings. "Calendar" should be listed and the toggle should be switched to the "on" position.

Then, in the upper right of the calendar application, press the three horizontal lines to display the menu. Press "Calendars" and check to make sure that the Google calendars that you want to sync with your phone are checked.

Finally, go to the menu in the upper right of the calendar application again, press "Sync," and the phone calendar should be updated to match the Google calendar.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not exactly my question. All the steps you have the kindness to describe were fulfilled. Some events are synced, in both directions, but some are not. That's the reason I want to make once a one-direction sync from the Google calendar to my phone.